# Xamarin android 13, Popup permission notification and Popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mONEs.jpg)

Hi developer,

Can i call this function for check permission and request permission popup in other file cs ? spesifik permission notification, photos and videos At the moment only can call this function in mainactivity.cs?

I have a need to call the function in other page ex : after login.

because this function it is called in mainactivity.cs so popup it will be called when the application open, can i call it other cs file than in mainactivity.cs ?

please help Thankyou.

Xamarin Android Developer

Answer (score 0):

> Can i call this function for check permission and request permission
> popup in other file cs ? At the moment only can call this function in
> mainactivity.cs?

Yes, you can call the function to check permissions and request permissions in other pages as you need.

For more information about Permissions in `Xamarin.Android`, you can check document [Permissions In Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows).

Besides, you can also use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials) nuget to achieve this.
The `Permissions` class in `Xamarin.Essentials` nuget provides the ability to check and request runtime permissions.

This API uses runtime permissions on Android. Please ensure that `Xamarin.Essentials` is fully initialized and permission handling is setup in your app.

For more information, you can check document [Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android).

Comment: My current problem is notification permissions, photos and videos. in specific android 13 api 33.
by default on the android app settings page, access notification permissions, photos and videos "not allow", I want the popup to be displayed on a page other than mainactivity.cs

can you please help me give an example code ?

thank you

Comment: You can add the code that asking the permissions to place that you want to add. For more details, you can refer to the official sample here : [RuntimePermissions](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/android-m/RuntimePermissions).